# Is it advisable to put JS in the footer? Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, seo

A query is a good practice to put the JS in the footer in magento 1.9.x?
In Google Speed ​​Test tells me that there are resources that clog the page when loading

Comment: yes , you can put your `js` in footer.

Comment: I declare it in the local.xml?

Comment: its okay.. not an issue bro..